# Microsoft Graph v5 - How to Patch and Get in same request?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I've upgraded the Microsoft Graph SDK to v5 on my project and I can't find a way to update and get a user in a single request. I have to PATCH and then GET. Althought the PATCH request returns a user, it is null.

Is it possible to specify the fields I want to be retrieved from the patched object?

This is what I do now:

```
var requestBody = new User { AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object> {{key , value}}};
await _graphClient.Users[user.Id].PatchAsync(requestBody);
var user =  await _graphClient.Users[user.Id].GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
   requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = _userAttributes;
});
```

This is what I would like:

```
var user = await _graphClient.Users[user.Id].PatchAsync(requestBody); //User has attributes filled
```

OR

```
 var user = await _graphClient.Users[user.Id].PatchAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
 {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = _userAttributes;
 });
```

Comment: This sounds like it's related to https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1682

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that:  Updating user using Patch request by default returns  `204 No Content` response code if it is successfull. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-update-properties-of-the-specified-user).

- When I tried to update the user using patch request, even I got the empty results, but user properties were updated.

Hence as a workaround, you have to make use of two separate calls for Patch and Get separately.

I used the below code, and **I am able to update the user properties and print them successfully** like below:

```cs
using Azure;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "ClientID";
var tenantId = "TenantID";
var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var requestBody = new User
{
    BusinessPhones = new List<string>
    {
        "xxx 2020",
    },
    OfficeLocation = "xx/2222",
};
var result = await graphClient.Users["UserID"].PatchAsync(requestBody);

var User = await graphClient.Users["UserID"].GetAsync((requestConfiguration) => { requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "OfficeLocation", "BusinessPhones", "displayName"}; });

foreach (var item in User.BusinessPhones)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Business Phone: " + item);
}
Console.WriteLine("Office Location: "+User.OfficeLocation);
Console.WriteLine("Display Name: "+User.DisplayName);
```

[image]

**In the Azure Portal**, the user attributes are updated:

[image]

I agree with *@Glen Scales*, according to this [**GitHub blog**](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1682) by *@PaulBujor*:

When I tried to pass the below request in the headers, I still got null values that is 204 No Content

- `Content-type: application/json`
- `Prefer: return=representation`

**Hence**, you have to make two requests to get for Get and Patch.

Comment: What's up buddy, yeah that's what I'm currently doing. But I was not happy with the solution because it forces me to do two requests. I wish Microsoft have done something more network performant :( I'll leave the ticked open for some more days and if no better answer appears I'll set yours as the correct  answer